# Determining the number of input channels in an AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, avaudiosession

I’m using AVCaptureSession to record input from the the device microphone.  I’d like to determine the number of input channels by examining `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().inputNumberOfChannels`.  If I look at it before recording begins, I get zero.  While the recording session is running, it correctly reports 1, but when recording stops it goes back to zero.  If possible, I’d like to set up my buffering before recording starts, rather than waiting until there’s data in the queue.  How can I do this?